# How to detect the selected section outside the tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here I want to detect which section has been selected as I am trying to delete the rows of the selected section only. Is there a way to identify which section has been detected? Here Rows return which rows has been selected. Similarly, I want to return which section has been selected.

```
func deleteSetUp() {

        let Rows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? []
        print("Here rows are \(Rows)")

        if(Rows.isEmpty){         
            self.wishListArr.removeAll()
//          self.dataArray.removeAll()

            self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        } else {
            let selectedRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!
            let deleteSpecificRows = selectedRows.count > 0

            if deleteSpecificRows { 
                let indicesOfItemsToDelete = NSMutableIndexSet()           
                for selectionIndex in selectedRows {
                    indicesOfItemsToDelete.addIndex(selectionIndex.row)
                }
       }
}
```

Comment: Never tried it and it may take some ingenuity, but gesture recognisers comes to mind.

Comment: Rows[0].section gives the section for first selected row

Answer (score 0):

Implement the delegate

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        headerView.tag = section
        let headerTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:"sectionHeaderTapped:")
        headerView .addGestureRecognizer(headerTapped)

        return headerView
    }
```

Now handle the tap here:

```
func sectionHeaderTapped(tapped: UITapGestureRecognizer){

        let section = tapped.view?.tag
        print(section) // number of section tapped
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

yup you can get that when you are suppose to call that

fun deleteSetUp()  function simply pass index path from tableView delegate and uses that index path to get the details i.e section and row to process further actions .

You can get that done in 2 ways

1.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
       self.deleteSetUp(indexPath)
}
func deleteSetUp(indexpath : NSIndexPath)
{
        let set = NSIndexSet(index: indexpath.section)
        self.tableview.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: index.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
}
```

2. for that one you must sure that you are selecting 1 row at a time

   ```
   func deleteSetUp()
   {
       let Rows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
       let index = Rows![0] 
       self.tableview.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: index.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

below code is not tested just try

```
    func deleteSetUp() {

    let Rows = self.aTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? []
    print("Here rows are \(Rows)")

    if(Rows.isEmpty){
        self.aTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
    else
    {
        let selectedRows = self.aTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!
        let deleteSpecificRows = selectedRows.count > 0

        if deleteSpecificRows {
            let indicesOfItemsToDelete = NSMutableIndexSet()

            for selectionIndex in selectedRows {
                indicesOfItemsToDelete.addIndex(selectionIndex.row)
            }
        }

        //indexpath contains both row and section info
        if selectedRows.count > 0 {
            let indecesSectionToDelete = NSMutableIndexSet()
            for selectionIndex in selectedRows {
                indecesSectionToDelete.addIndex(selectionIndex.section) //hear u will get the which section to delete 
            }
        }
    }
}
```